# Чтение файла внешних ресурсов

Tags: java, android, io

Как я могу прочитать ранее записанный файл? Я не могу обратиться к нему и указать путь. Вот коды записи и чтения.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("textfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
bw.write("wdadawdawdaw");
bw.close();
```

Здесь я пытаюсь прочитать файл но имя подсвечивает красным.

```
 InputStream is = openFileInput();
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `InputStream is = openFileInput("textfile");`

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В метод [`openFileInput(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)) необходимо передать имя файла:

```
InputStream is = openFileInput("textfile");
```